# How to count only certain rows in a GROUP BY in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

In the application I'm building, there are posts and tags, and they are connected through a many-to-many relation. What I want to do is show all tags to the user and sort them by how many published posts they have (which is determined by the is_published column in the posts table).

Right now I'm sorting them by how many posts they have in general (both published and unpublished) with this code:

```
scope :top_used, -> { left_joins(:posts).group(:id).order("COUNT(posts.id) DESC") }
```

Which translates to the MySQL:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM tags t
  LEFT 
  JOIN post_tags pt
    ON pt.tag_id = tags.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN posts p
    ON p.id = pt.post_id 
 GROUP 
    BY t.id  
 ORDER 
    BY COUNT(p.id) DESC
```

So, again, I need to sort by the count of the number of published posts not all posts. Can this be done in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `post_tags` ON `post_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`id` = `post_tags`.`post_id` AND posts.is_published = 1
GROUP BY `tags`.`id` 
ORDER BY COUNT(posts.id) DESC
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the column `is_published`'s data type is `Boolean` or `Integer`, with values `1` or `0` you can order by the sum of the values:

```
ORDER BY SUM(posts.is_published) DESC
```

If `is_published` is nullable, use `COALESCE()`:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(SUM(posts.is_published), 0) DESC
```